Creating Module gives The command or action 'NewObjectModule' isn't available now
I have an add-in that i have created with an add new module function. Here is the code:
Public Function CreateModule(strModulename As String)
      Dim strModName As String
10       On Error GoTo err
20       DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdNewObjectModule
30       strModName = "Module1"
40       DoCmd.Save acModule, strModName
50       DoCmd.Rename strModulename, acModule, strModName
60       DoCmd.Save acModule, strModulename
ExitHere:
70       Exit Function
80 err:                      Call LogError("CreateModule-Utils")
End Function

When i run it gives an error "The command or action 'NewObjectModule' isn't available now.". However if i put a break and step through it gives no error and works properly have tried sleep and DoEvent to no avail. Any ideas appreciated.
type here


Not seen numbered BASIC statements from GWBASIC and Commodore Basic time era.

Try using the VBA Extensibility library:
Public Sub AddModule(ByVal ModuleName As String)
 
    Dim vbp As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim vbc As VBIDE.VBComponent
    
    Dim currentVbProject As String
    
    currentVbProject = Application.GetOption("Project Name")
    Set vbp = Application.VBE.VBProjects(currentVbProject)
    Set vbc = vbp.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
    vbc.Name = ModuleName
    
    ' Insert code.
    vbc.CodeModule.InsertLines 4, "Public Sub HelloWorld" & vbCrLf & " MsgBox(""Hello, World!"") " & vbCrLf & "End Sub"

    ' Save module.
    DoCmd.Save acModule, ModuleName
    
    Set vbp = Nothing
    Set vbc = Nothing
    
End Sub

Required reference:
Microsoft Visual Basic for Application Extensibility 5.3
Original code: Philipp Stiefel Codekabinett
